# Cannot make the header smaller

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to make my header smaller with padding and margin but every time I do that it doesn't work.

```css
body{
    background-color: rgb(20, 9, 59);
    margin: 0%;
    padding: 0%;
    color: aliceblue;
    position: relative;
}


header {
background: black;
position:relative;
margin-bottom: 200px
}


h1{
font-size: 35px;
margin-left: 640px;
position: relative;
}


ul{
margin: 0%;
padding: 0%;
list-style-type: none;
position: relative;
}


li {
display: inline-block;
margin: 5px;
position: relative;
padding-left: 1200px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head><title>TextAhnaf</title></head> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Styles.css">
  <body>
    
    <header>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="Login.html">Login</a></li>
                <h4>Contact</h4>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <h1>Text</h1>
    </header>
  </body>
</html>
```

[This is what the website looks currently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/083L5.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO, you will need to be more specific. What do you mean smaller? what is it supposed to look like? If it is too hard to describe, draw us a picture.

Comment: I want to make the height smaller

Answer (score 0):

If i understand well what you want to do.

You need to set a max-width rule to your tag header and then set margin: 0 auto, to centered your block.

```
margin: 0 auto;
max-width: 920px;
```

```css
body{
    background-color: rgb(20, 9, 59);
    margin: 0%;
    padding: 0%;
    color: aliceblue;
    position: relative;
}


header {
background: black;
position:relative;
margin: 0 auto;
max-width: 920px;
height: 200px;
}


h1{
font-size: 35px;
margin-left: 640px;
position: relative;
}


ul{
margin: 0%;
padding: 0%;
list-style-type: none;
position: relative;
}


li {
display: inline-block;
margin: 5px;
position: relative;
padding-left: 1200px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head><title>TextAhnaf</title></head> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Styles.css">
  <body>
    
    <header>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="Login.html">Login</a></li>
                <h4>Contact</h4>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <h1>Text</h1>
    </header>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: sorry, I thing i phrase the question wrong. I meant to say I can't change the height of my header aka the black part top of the page

Comment: @AhnafTajwar just add the rule height to your header tag: height:200px;
I edited my post.

Answer (score -1):

Move your CSS link inside the head element

```
<head>
  <title>TextAhnaf</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Styles.css">
</head>
```